# jquery validate conflict with script preventing double submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, submit-button

I'm using a form generated by Toolset CRED plugin that has jquery.validate validation.
I've got issues with duplicated content generated when user clicks repeatedly the submit button.

I've tried to add this code to prevent multiple submissions

```
    $("form").submit(function() {
        // submit more than once return false
        $(this).submit(function() {
            return false;
        });
        // submit once return true
        return true;
    });
```

It works fine except the fact that if the first time the user submits the form it doesn't pass the validation then the submit button doesn't work anymore.

Could you suggest any tweak?
Thanks
Carlo

Answer (score -1):

You could create a global variable and check whether it's been changed.
Then assuming it's a regular form, the page would reload and you could send the form again.

```
var hasBeenSent = false;

$("form").on('submit',function(e){
   if(hasBeenSent != false){
       e.preventDefault(); // this should prevent sending the form.
   }else{
       hasBeenSent = true;
   }   
})
```

Comment: The one huge problem with this idea is that the jQuery Validate plugin has its own built-in submit handler function.